# Let $f: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be an analytic function on $\Omega$. Show that $f′$ is also analytic on $\Omega$.

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, analytic-functions

I'm trying to understand analytic functions in the correct ways before it's too late so that I don't get lost later.

Problem:

Let $\Omega$ be an open set and let $f: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be an analytic function on $\Omega$. Show that $f′$ is also analytic on $\Omega$.

My (fixed) approach

> Let $z_0$ be an arbitrary point in $\Omega$. Since $f$ is analytic at
> $z_0$, $\exists S(z)=\sum a_k(z-z_0)^k$ with radius of convergence
> $R>0$ s.t $f(z) = S(z)$, $\forall z\in B(z_0,R)$.
>
> Note that, $S(z)$ is holomorphic on $B(z_0,R)$, and analytic functions are holomorphic.
>
> $\Rightarrow f'(z)=S'(z)$, $\forall z\in B(z_0,R)$ where $S'(z)$ has
> radius of convergence $R$ and centered at $z_0$.
>
> $\Rightarrow f'$ is analytic on $B(z_0,R)$ by definition.
>
> But, since $z_0$ is an arbitrary point, $f'$ is analytic on $\Omega$. $\blacksquare $

Any comments or corrections are welcomed. Thank you.

Comment: You should fix a point first and then write the power series around that point (that is, in a "small" enough ball around the point you fixed). Once you have this, then to take the derivative term by term, you will require uniform convergence of the power series. Do you have this with you?

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh So, we should stick with the definition of analytic functions (not changing it). But, we want to show this definition works for an arbitrary point in $\Omega$. Am I understanding your comment right? And, is the uniform convergence coming from the properties of the radius of convergence?

Comment: You always have to stick with given definitions (you cannot *change* them). What you have written in the first line is true for a small ball around $z = 0$. But we don't know if $0 \in \Omega$. So, I said you should take an arbitrary point and write the power series around that point. Indeed, using translations you can shift any point in $\Omega$ to origin to make the calculations easy. But then you also have to remember shifting everything back to the original point.

Comment: Uniform convergence will not happen in the open ball. It will happen in every compact set contained in the open ball. You can look at any standard books on complex analysis. You will find this result there. Only for uniformly convergent power series, you can take the derivative term by term. If the convergence is not uniform, then we cannot do it.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh I feel so lucky to have your comments! Thank you very much!

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh I just edited the proof thanks to you. Does the proof still need corrections?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hesitate to call this proof *wrong* but it reads a bit weirdly to me. The core idea, which you seem to grasp, is that $f'(z)=\frac{d}{dz}\sum a_k(z-z_0)^k$. However you can use this fact to do much more than merely prove the existence of a power series for $f'(z)$, you can use it to explicitly construct one!

The way I would recommend proving this is showing that $f'(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_{k+1}(z-z_0)^{k}$, and then computing its radius of convergence. You'll find that it is $R$, and then be done.

Comment: Thank you. I used a proposition 'Differentiability of power series' from my textbook,  which tells us that if $S(z):= \sum a_kz^k$ with the finite radius of convergence $R$, then $S(z)$ is complex differentiable on $B(0,R)$, and $S'(z)$ also has radius of convergence $R$. I just replaced $0$ with $z_0$ because I thought it was doable. And combining it with another proposition in my textbook, which says $f(z) =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }a_n(z-z_0)^n$ with radius of convergence $R$ and centered at $z_0$ has a convergent power series centered at $z_1 \in B(z_0,R)$ given by

Comment: $f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty }b_k(z-z_1)^k$, for $\left |z-z_1  \right |<R - \left |z_1-z_0  \right |$. This implies $f$ is analytic on an openball around $z_0$.

Comment: Did I use these propositions incorrectly?

Comment: I fixed my proof again to make it more readable. Do you think it needs any more correction?

Comment: @john No, you used them correctly. I did not have this context though. It's a good habit to get into to say "by proposition 2.4 in the textbook" when making deductions like that. Even if your professor knows the content you've covered, it's a good way to demonstrate that you know exactly what's going on.